# Asp.NET MVC Form entry displayed as link to external site?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, href

I have a view which includes code like so:

```
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegistrationLink)
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RegistrationLink)
    </dd>
```

The idea is a user enters a link to their website into the form. Then on my website it displays as a link a person can click to go to that site. Please help if this is possible.
I tried using
`< a href="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RegistrationLink)"></a>`
but unfortunately that won't work.

Comment: Try this once. 

<a href="@model.RegistrationLink" target="_blank" >@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegistrationLink)</a>

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your advice, issue resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to format your link in the view model like so:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private string link = "http://www.google.com";

    public string RenderLink {
        get
        {
            return $"<a href='{link}'> {link} </a>";
        }
    }
}
```

After that you can you use @Html.Raw to show html code in your razor view:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.RenderLink)
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your advice, issue resolved.